# Handling events for a collection of JButtons

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, event-handling

I'm attempting to create dynamic interface that essentially creates a grid of a growing number of panels that look similar to the picture below. I've got some rough code to achieve that. I have an issue in regards to handling events for the JButtons that i've added to an ArrayList. I'm aware that creating inner class event handlers is best practise, how would I handle events for a scaling number of buttons that are stored in an ArrayList?

Currently i've resulted to getting the objects source to achieve this.

[image: Example of one of the panels]

Global Variables:

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
```

Adding buttons to the panel:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
        int xTotal = 150;
        if (i == 0) {
            xTotal = 132;
        }
        else {
            xTotal = 308;
        }
        xTotal = xTotal + xTotal;

        JButton currentButton = new JButton("+");
        currentButton.setBounds(xTotal , 375, 45, 25); 
        currentButton.setFont(currentButton.getFont().deriveFont(14f));
        currentButton.addActionListener(new AddHandler());

        buttons.add(currentButton);
        panel.add(currentButton);
    }
```

Event handler:

```
class AddHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


        Object source = event.getSource();

        if (source == buttons.get(0)) {
            System.out.println("hello");

        }
        else {

            System.out.println("it worked");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach, i'd say.

Comment: Hmm performance would eventually become an issue and using source is considered bad practise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you're creating more than just a collection of `JButtons`. Instead you appear to be wanting to create (and correct me if I'm wrong), a collection of images/text with `JButton`. This suggests that you want to create a class that encapsulates *one* (?) menu item, that holds a JLabel for the image, a `JLabel` perhaps for the text, perhaps other components, and a `JButton` that the user can press to select the menu item. This component would be a JPanel that (important here) uses layout managers to intelligently arrange all of its constituent components. I would recommend not using `ActionListeners` but rather create a separate stand along class that extends `AbstractAction`, that you can use to set each `JButton`'s `Action`, either via the `JButton`'s constructor or via its `setAction(...)` method. Then you could place a collection of these JPanels in a master `JPanel` that uses perhaps a `GridLayout`, and have it held in a `JScrollPane`.

The details of my suggestions and the code would of course depend on the details of your GUI and your current code.

Other "side" recommendations:

- Don't use `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)`. Often newbie Swing programmers feel that this is the easiest way to create complex GUI's, and in the short term it may be, but in the long term, when it comes time to maintain, upgrade and enhance your GUI, it isn't. Also the GUI's so created may look OK on one platform and screen resolution, but they look terrible on all others. Learn about and use the layout managers.
- Maybe you want a collection of Actions or the JButtons, but I'm not sure you need this. If the button's Action knows what to do, then no collection is needed. The Action could have a constructor that passes in references to the name and price of the menu item.

Comment: Yeah thats what I'd like to achieve. Thanks I'll definately give that a go.

Comment: Aha thank you! Looks like I have allot of reading to do to figure this out, would be leaps and bounds over what I've done in previous projects.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, had the chance to give it a go the past few days and my god was it a lot easier to implement then I initialy thought. Layout managers are definitely the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Even though youve already accepted another answer, I want to share what I have on my mind.

The idea of my idea is to store a number (maybe an ID) on the button by creating a subclass of JButton.
(ID could be, perhaps the ID of the food item this button is currently linked to)

```
class FoodButton extends JButton{
    long id;

    public FoodButton(String text, long id){
        super(text);
        this.id = id;
    }
    //Perhaps more constructors

    public long getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then writing a single actionListener that gets the source of the event (even though you seem to think thats bad practice, I think it makes sense in this example), Observe:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        FoodButton btn = (FoodButton) e.getSource();
        long id = btn.getId();

        //Do something now that you know what button was clicked (id)
    }
}
```

Let me note again that this actionListener is created **before** your loop, so you only need one, and you'll assign the same one to all your buttons.

Then inside your loop instead of creating a normal JButton, you create a FoodButton:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){...};
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
    //...

    //Assigning id 'i' here, but you could pick something else
    JButton currentButton = new FoodButton("+", i);
    //...
    currentButton.addActionListener(al);

    buttons.add(currentButton);
    panel.add(currentButton);
}
```

I hope this makes some sense to you.

Also, as someone who used to use null layouts too, once you get accustomed to using layoutmanagers, im sure you will like them.

Comment: Seems like a good solution I've just been taught that using source to handle events is bad because its more resource hungry, might give it a go makes sense to me, I'm a little sketchy around some OO concepts being quite new.